# Merging dataframe with two separate conditions

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to learn time series with the help of https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/store-sales-time-series-forecasting and ran into a problem with the merging. I have merged everything else except for holidays_events together.

So my merged_df.head() looks currently like

```
 id       date  store_nbr     family  sales  onpromotion  dcoilwtico  city     state type  cluster  transactions
  0 2013-01-01          1 AUTOMOTIVE    0.0            0         NaN Quito Pichincha    D       13           NaN
  1 2013-01-01          1  BABY CARE    0.0            0         NaN Quito Pichincha    D       13           NaN
  2 2013-01-01          1     BEAUTY    0.0            0         NaN Quito Pichincha    D       13           NaN
  3 2013-01-01          1  BEVERAGES    0.0            0         NaN Quito Pichincha    D       13           NaN
  4 2013-01-01          1      BOOKS    0.0            0         NaN Quito Pichincha    D       13           NaN
```

and holidays_events.head() looks like

```
      date    type   locale locale_name                   description  transferred
2012-03-02 Holiday    Local       Manta            Fundacion de Manta        False
2012-04-01 Holiday Regional    Cotopaxi Provincializacion de Cotopaxi        False
2012-04-12 Holiday    Local      Cuenca           Fundacion de Cuenca        False
2012-04-14 Holiday    Local    Libertad     Cantonizacion de Libertad        False
2012-04-21 Holiday    Local    Riobamba     Cantonizacion de Riobamba        False
```

The 'locale_name' column contains some city names because some holidays are specific to only some cities. But there is also a value 'Ecuador' which should apply to everything.

I tried the following code but obviously it's just a big mess with a lot of duplicate columns

```
ecuador = holidays_events.loc[holidays_events["locale_name"] == "Ecuador"].copy()
nonecuador = holidays_events.loc[holidays_events["locale_name"] != "Ecuador"].copy()

merged_df = merged_df.merge(nonecuador, left_on=['date', 'city'], right_on=['date', 'locale_name'], how='left')
merged_df = merged_df.merge(ecuador, on='date', how='left')
```

So what my question is: Is there some way to merge the holiday_events into merged_df so that ever row with value 'Ecuador' in 'locale_name' column would be merged on='date' and other values would be merged left_on=['date', 'city'], right_on=['date', 'locale_name']? Or is there some workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a mess, just code explicitly what you would like to achieve. I guess one column with the name of the holiday should be enough:

#### Full solution

```
merged_df["holiday"] = False
for holiday in holiday_events.itertuples():
    if holiday.locale_name == "Ecuador":
        mask = True
    elif holiday.locale == "Regional":
        mask = merged_df["state"] == holiday.locale_name
    elif holiday.locale == "Local":
        mask = merged_df["city"] == holiday.locale_name
    date_mask = merged_df["date"] == holiday.date
    targets = merged_df.loc[date_mask & mask, "holiday"]
    assert not targets.any()
    targets = holiday.description
```

#### Explanation

`merged_df["holiday"] = False` initializes the column with the value `False`. You could leave out this line; then the column would be populated with Nones as soon as you add the first item. EDIT: Alternatively, you can use another Python object instead of `False`, such as the string `"no"`.

[`itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) is the simplest way to iterate over DataFrame rows. It converts every row to a convenient [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).
You can access each item of the namedtuple (a copy of the row) `holiday` via the column name and attribute access as in `holiday.locale_name`.

So for the first row:

```
      date    type   locale locale_name                   description  transferred
2012-03-02 Holiday    Local       Manta            Fundacion de Manta        False
```

the `if-elif`-chain reduces to:

```
    if "Manta" == "Ecuador":  # False
        ...
    elif "Local" == "Regional":  # False
        ...
    elif "Local" == "Local":  # True
        mask = merged_df["city"] == "Manta"
```

The `mask` and `date_mask` objects are just Pandas Series objects filled with `True` and `False` values. (In the `"Ecuador"` clause, I've just put `True`. Pandas broadcasts that later.)

`merged_df.loc[date_mask & mask, "holiday"]` does boolean-AND between the two masks, uses the resulting mask (of the same shape) to index the rows via `.loc`, an hence results in a view into the appropriate fields in the "holiday" column.

`assert not targets.any()` checks if any of the fields are already filled. This can happen if your holiday database has duplicates. If this raises an `AssertionError`, you need to think about how to deal with these. ([More on `assert`](https://realpython.com/python-assert-statement/))

`targets = holiday.description` inserts the name of the holiday into all fields identified by `targets`.

#### Dictionary alternative

You can remove a little code repetition and hence save a few characters by using a dictionary instead of the `if`-`elif`-chain. I assume `holiday.locale == "National"` for the whole country but you'd have to check in your DataFrame what the actual value is.

```
merged_df["holiday"] = False
locale_levels = {
    "National": "Ecuador",
    "Regional": merged_df["state"],
    "Local": merged_df["city"],
}
for holiday in holiday_events.itertuples():
    place_mask = locale_levels[holiday.locale] == holiday.locale_name
    date_mask = merged_df["date"] == holiday.date
    targets = merged_df.loc[date_mask & place_mask, "holiday"]
    assert not targets.any()
    targets = holiday.description
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little not-specific (a peace of code + output would help)
To try and answer your question - try to use a split by your condition and than 2 merge commands.

something like:

```
#  'Ecuador' in 'locale_name' column would be merged on='date' 
df1 = df.loc[df["locale_name"] == "Ecuador"].copy()
df2 = df.loc[df["locale_name"] != "Ecuador"].copy()

df1 = df1.merge(other, on = "date", how="left")
#other values would be merged left_on=['date', 'city'], right_on=['date', 'locale_name']
df2 = df2.merge(other, left_on=['date', 'city'], right_on=['date', 'locale_name'])

final_df = df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't quite what I am looking for. I tried to add a bit of clarification.